# How can i add item to array of web service class?

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-services

I am using a SOAP web service that includes its own class.
Web Service recieve an array and I want to create many items and add them to the array but I don't know how.

Here is my code:

> *wshr = Name of web service

```
        wshr.HConductor _HCond = new wshr.HConductor();
        _HCond.TpoDocumento = "L.E.";
        _HCond.NroDocumento = "12345678";
        _HCond.FecInicio = "27/02/2016";
        _HCond.HorInicio = "08:00";
        _HCond.FecTermino = "27/02/2016";
        _HCond.HorTermino = "09:00";
        wshr.HConductor[] listaConductores = new wshr.HConductor[]
        {
            _HCond
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 wshr.HConductor[] listaConductores = new wshr.HConductor[5]

        listaConductores[0]= yourlistaConductores1
        listaConductores[1]= yourlistaConductores2
        listaConductores[2]= yourlistaConductores3
        listaConductores[3]= yourlistaConductores4
        listaConductores[4]= yourlistaConductores5
```

Comment: I am not asking about how to use the web service. My question is about how to use an array for that web service. If I could find the autor of the web service, i didn't ask here.